# mysqldump export not complete

Tags: cron, mysql

My hosting provider had a huge corruption issue last week following a power failure. As a result, I had to import all databases again from a backup.

Our backup runs daily (using cron.daily) and each database is exported using mysqldump. Each database is gzipped and sent to storage.

Unfortunately, one of the databases have been incorrectly exporting for some time which I've just found out now. It's not the largest export at around 130MB (uncompressed).

The below is the output from mysqldump, I get the same output from SSH and from cron.daily. Obviously, this is incomplete!

I'm just trying to identify why this may have happened so I can avoid it in the future.

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.5.24, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: *********************
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

Comment: have you tried running the command manually ? whats the exact mysqldump command you are using ?

Comment: take a look at the output logs from cron. disk space?

Comment: @MadDokMike I've run the mysqldump manually and get the same output. The command in our script is:

`mysql -s -r -u backup -p******** -e 'show databases' | while read db; do mysqldump -u backup -p******** $db -r /tmp/db-bup/${db}.sql; [[ $? -eq 0 ]] && gzip /tmp/db-bup/${db}.sql; done`

Comment: @Jeff There are no issues with disk space. I have a much larger database which didn't have any issues exporting using the same technique.

Comment: i presume when you do mysqldump -u backup -p******** $db -r /tmp/db-bup/${db}.sql; as a single command with your DB name replacing $db that you still get a broken file ? can the backup user see $db and has the correct privelleges on them DBs ?

Comment: Sometimes one table is corrupt and this will break the mysqldump. Maybe this was also the case in your situation?